# Kotlin Android Extensions: How to get a reference to a view in a layout that gets included into another layout?

Tags: kotlin-android-extensions

I have a layout that includes another layout:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"/>

    <include layout="@layout/included_layout" />

</LinearLayout>
```

included_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/includedTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Included TextView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I get a reference to the TextView in the included layout? Is it not supported (yet)?

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textView.text = "text" // works!
        textViewInclude.text = "textInclude" // does not work: "Unresolved reference: textViewInclude "
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should `import` the included layout.

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.included_layout.* // Here

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // From activity_main.textView
        textView.text = "text" 

        // From included_layout.textViewInclude
        textViewInclude.text = "textInclude"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't it simply import automatically?

Comment: im having the same issue, when I import this line: import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.included_layout.*
i get an issue ( unresolved reference : kotlinx )
can you help please ?

Comment: what about if you have two includes of the same layout?

Comment: doesn't work if the layout is i another module, unfortunately. is there any solution to this? am i missing something?

Comment: my not working still null pointer on other layout view

Comment: Although this post is a bit older I want to add for completeness: You need to add and apply the `kotlin-android-extensions` in your `build.gradle` in order to import from your layout directly. Please find how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169562/unresolved-reference-kotlinx)

Comment: As @Tobias mentioned, you need to apply `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin in the `build.gradle`. Any idea why it isn't applied by default in some cases?

Answer (score 0):

In the Activity where you want acess of other layout element implement click Listner

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
 
 override fun onClick(view: View?) {
    when (view?.id) {
        R.id.dialog_cancel-> { dialog.cancel() }
    }
  }
}
```

in the another layout  which you are importing in your Activity, place onClick() in the element and refrence it to the Activity where you imported onClick listner
android:onClick="onClick"

[image]

It will work definetly and the another xml element will listen the click