# Unresolved reference: kotlinx

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to try out Kotlin and the Kotlin Android extensions in Android Studio.  I have tried this both in Android Studio v 1.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, and in Android Studio v 1.5.1 on OS X El Capitan with the same result.

Here is what I am doing:

1. I install the Kotlin plugin 1.0.0-beta-35950-IJ141-11
2. Create a new blank Android project
3. Convert the MainActivity file to Kotlin (via help->findaction->convert file to kotlin)
4. Configure the project for Kotlin

I then go into the generated content_main.xml file and add an id (hello) for the "Hello World!" TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.gmail.npnster.mykotlinfirstproject.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in the converted MainActivity I add a line to set the TextView. (shown below).
Android Studio then prompts me (via alt-enter) to insert this line (also shown below)

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*
```

So at this point everything *seems* fine

but then when I try to compile this I get

```
Unresolved reference: kotlinx
Unresolved reference: kotlinx
Unresolved reference: hello
```

Notice that I did **not** install the Kotlin Android extensions plugin.  As of a couple of days ago this is now supposed to be included in the main plug in and is marked as obsolete.  (In fact if you try to install it when you have the latest plugin, nothing new is installed)

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
import android.view.View
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        print("setting text view value to hey")
        hello.text = "hey"

        val fab = findViewById(R.id.fab) as FloatingActionButton
        fab.setOnClickListener { view -> Snackbar.make(view, "Replace this with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show() }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        val id = item.itemId

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: My solution was completely different, I removed the Kotlin language support as official from gradle.properties file and it worked again. Actually, the file got corrupted and has some random strings, I fixed it by going back to random strings.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Add `kotlin-android-extensions` in our buildscript's dependencies:

**1. In your project-level build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

and apply the `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin:

**2. In your module-level build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Comment: That's what I did but I still get the issue with 1.0.0-beta-3595 :(

Comment: Does not work for me either (1.0.0-beta-4589) - any solution yet? Just added a comment to the ticket in the bug tracker.

Comment: I also had this issue on 1.0.0-beta-4589.  You also have to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` to your build.gradle file

Comment: Better expressed with a $kotlin_version variable: `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"`

Comment: Also note if you fullfill this anwer, the invalidate caches/restart may help

Comment: Does not work for me. I'm using AS 3.1.3 and Gradle 3.1.3 (Both latest as of July 2018). The project was recently upgraded to this config, and the unresolved reference started coming for a few Kotlin lines(one was removeOnGlobalLayoutListener). Been stuck on this for 5 days. Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Does not work for me either. I'm having this issue after upgrading to Android Studio 3.3 (used to work with 3.2).

Comment: @hardysim and why exactly is this is a reason to give me a downvote for the solution which worked for 167 other users (at least accordingly to the number of upvotes)?

Comment: @aga maybe it's a thin line between "not correct (for me) so not useful" (downvote) and "not correct (for me) but maybe useful for others" (no vote). plus, this should work without adding `kotlin-android-extensions` to the classpath (as it used to). But fine, I'm going to not use the downvote again anywhere if it's not obviously incorrect. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: How to apply it to bazel?

Comment: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

Answer (score 39):

When you use Android Studio 2.0 and kotlin 1.0.1-2, you will come up with the same wrong. You cann't configure kotlin android extensions in your project's build.gradle, you need to configure and kotlin android extensions in every Module's build.gradle like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.1-2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dazd.kotlindemo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
       main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Most importantly, even through the kotlin plugin included the kotlin android extension, you also need to configure the kotlin-android-extensions in your Module's bulid.gradle like this:

```
...
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
...
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
```

Of course, you could configure the kotlin plugin's classpath in your project's build.gradle.

Comment: In my case (Android Studio 2.1.1, kotlin 1.0.2) the "Configure kotlin in Project" action configured kotlin in project build.gradle instead of Module's build.gradle, and this helped.

Comment: Check your `ext.kotlin_version` and add `classpath...` mentioned above in the project gradle. And add the two `apply...` to app gradle.

Answer (score 37):

I can't find it in the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html), but you must apply the plugin by adding the following to your `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Comment: Yes, I think since the `kotlin-1.0.0-beta` you need to apply the plugin, but I can't find a source for that! Thanks!

Comment: Note: Official documentation has been updated: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#using-kotlin-android-extensions

Comment: Request an edit over the accepted answer and append this info! :)

Comment: The official documentation now shows an empty code block where the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` should be.

Answer (score 12):

The buildscript block containing the kotlin-android-extensions dependency apparently needs to be in the app-module build.gradle, not in the top-level one.

Comment: I thought it would be something like this; most of my karma is from answering a gradle question with a similar issue.

Answer (score 8):

I found why mine didn't work. My blocks were misplaced and by moving the `buildscript{}` block before the plugins as follow I got it working:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0-beta-3595'
    ext.anko_version = '0.8.1'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kotlin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:$anko_version"
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Would you happen to know why that fixed it?

Comment: The only answer showing exactly where the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` needs to be added ... +1

Comment: But why this fix it?

Answer (score 8):

Removing the following import fixed the issue for me.

```
import android.R
```

Comment: https://georgik.rocks/android-studio-unresolved-reference-activity_main-r-layout-and-r-id/

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to find a fix for this problem. GRADLE files were not a problem. Thank you very much sir, only this worked for me! Again, Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Dude!!! i also spend a lot of time with extensions xD

Answer (score 6):

add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` in `app/buildgradle`.

if you have already added it, try to remove it and sync gradle, when sync is complete, then add it back and Sync Gradle again. This work for me.

Answer (score 6):

The problem for me was the order in which I applied the plugins.

You must apply the kotlin-android plugin before the kotlin-android-extensions plugin

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me in Android Studio 4.2 Beta 1 in macOS big sur to add `id 'kotlin-android-extensions'` to plugin section in app-level `build.gradle` file. So that it should look as follows.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Then sync the project and it should work

Answer (score 4):

With jetpack you have to use:

in the `build.gradle` (app)

```
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }

   plugins {
      id 'kotlin-parcelize'
   }
```

In `activity_main.xml`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    tools:viewBindingIgnore="false">
```

In `MainActivity.kt`

```
import com.example.appname.databinding.ActivityMainBinding // ActivityMain is for main_activity.xml, and so on for any other activity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {} // use binding.elementName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After applying the fixes mentioned above, I had to restart Android Studio to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the year 2021 then i guess most of the solutions you see here wont be of any help to you so try this instead

1. Go to your Module build.gradle file
2. add id 'kotlin-android-extensions' to the plugins object {}
3. Go to file the click on sync project with gradle files

Then go back and try to import kotlinx and that should work

Comment: the problem is that kotlin-android-extensions is deprecated and should't be used

Answer (score 1):

In my case, adding:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

at the end of the module-level `build.grade` fixed the issue.

Comment: This appears to be the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551152/10871073) (but with less explanation).

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
}
```

removed `apply plugin:` to `id`and restarted

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id "kotlin-kapt"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me.
When I first configured Kotlin in Project, I selected the 1.1.2-3 version instead of 1.1.2-4 and added the following line in the build.gradle app file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

after that I synced the build and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I had support for C++ and Kotlin at the same time which was causing build problems.

When starting a new project, ensure C++ support is unchecked, and Kotlin support is checked. That fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had put the code referring the view in a `companion object`. How silly..

Answer (score 0):

For me the only thing that helped was to click "File" -> "Invalidate caches / Restart..."

Answer (score 0):

in my case android studio line separator changed to CRLF( I am using macbook) windows  settings.
when switch to CR fix my error

Answer (score 0):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

For me I just had to add `id 'kotlin-android-extensions'` to plugins in build.gradle(Module:AppName.app)
And Sync it after that.

Answer (score 0):

use this plug-in in your app project "Gradle script" folder in file "build.Gradle (Modules : progect_name)" :
"Kotlin-android-extensions"
then sync the projects.