# kotlinx.android.synthetic not recognising resources when resources existing in different module

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have "assets" module containing all my resources (layout, strings, values, etc) and I added this module as dependency in "app". Now when I try to refer ids using kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.xyzId.view.* , it is unable to resolve "xyzId". But when resources are directly put in same "app" module in res folder then it's working correctly. Does it means that kotlinx-android-extension do not work for resources lying in dependent module?

Comment: Duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378696/unresolved-reference-for-synthetic-view-when-layout-is-in-library-module