# Can't access view elements by LayoutInflater in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I simply made an adapter for my **recyclerview**.like this :

```
class CustomerAdapter(mCtx:Context,val customers:ArrayList<Customer>):RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomerAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
```

and i have a xml layout file to inflate recycleview items.

But the problem is in `onCreateViewHolder` ... I can not access inflated elements ...

codes writed in my onCreateViewHolder method :

```
  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomerAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lo_customers, parent, false);
        var txt = v.id

    }
```

i can not access view elements by id .

[image]

Comment: Do you have imported the synthetic layout at the kotlin file?

Comment: yep ! i forget adding `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.lo_customers.view.*` and thanks for reminder

Comment: Synthetic is deprecated, consider migrating to view binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At gradle app

```
plugins {
   id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Or

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Then your Activity Import this

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

Comment: The plugin `kotlin-android-extensions` is **deprecated**. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65179275/the-kotlin-android-extensions-gradle-plugin-is-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Even if you capture the `View`, you cannot directly access the children's in the `View`. In-order to get hold of children's you need to use
`findViewById(R.id.my_textView_id)` on the `View` object.

Hence replace your `v.txt` by `v.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view_id)`.

Comment: this is **kotlin** Not **Java**.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely the wrong way to do it . onCreateViewHolder the function name itself says that it is meant only for inflating the view and doing nothing else. It should only be used for creating the ViewHolder . Even if you inflate your view and assign view from there , it is going to crash in the future . You have to inflate the view there and pass the parent view to another class which should extend RecyclerView.ViewHolder() .

So do it the following way :

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomerAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lo_customers, parent, false);
   
    }
```

Create an ViewHolder Class extending RecyclerView.ViewHolder :

```
 class CustomViewHolder(val view: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        fun bind(model  : Model) {

         //Now here you can access all the components present in your layout in the following way and do the stuff you want with them: 
           val text = view.findViewById(R.id.viewid)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to access from android.R, rather try like this:

CategoryAdapterHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(com.example.secondhand.R.layout.category_list, parent, false))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).