# Android Kotlin - viewBindinding not working

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I follower this instruction:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65903308/10642456

from the answer from "Geek Tanmoy"

but I still have `unresolved Reference` on most views also when adding `binding.` before them, it just doesn't do anything.

What could be the problem?

This is an example:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.skipProfileImage.setOnClickListener {
        finish()
    } 
}
```

`Unresolved reference` on `skipProfileImage`

EDIT:

This is not the ActivityMain but another one and I'll share it because it's the one where the error appears first when I rebuild project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#303030"
    tools:context=".AskProfileImage">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView97545"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView97545">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/upload_a_profile_image"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAlmostWhite"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/chooseProfileImage"
            android:layout_width="104dp"
            android:layout_height="104dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle"
                app:tint="@color/colorWhite" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/askProfileImageCam"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera"
                app:tint="@color/colorText" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chooseProfileImageAlternative"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/tap_to_choose_an_image"
            android:textColor="@color/colorThemeSecond"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/skipProfileImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/Skip"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextBitDarker"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try running the code, sometimes compile time error remains, even if there were no error.

Comment: can u please post some code and logcat!
Punishing someone will not help you

Comment: the log has thousands of rows, this is one randomly picket tiny part of it: 2021-09-24 20:27:53.611 22223-23567/? D/GOS:GlobalSettingsContainer: setRecommendedMode(), [0, 1, 2, 3]
2021-09-24 20:27:53.611 3664-3834/? D/StorageManagerService: getExternalStorageMountMode : final mountMode=1, uid : 10025, packageName : com.samsung.android.game.gamehome
2021-09-24 20:27:53.611 22223-23567/? D/GOS:GlobalSettingsContainer: setEnabledFeatureFlag(), src : 342277969731031827, result : 54047593575125267

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Can you `Build > Make Project` and see

Comment: Same as rebuild project @Zain

Comment: Can you share the activity_main.xml?

Comment: Ok check out the edit

Comment: Wrap your `ConstraintLayout` in `<layout> </layout>` tag as `<layout><ConstraintLayout>...</ConstraintLayout></layout>`, it will work.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar it didn't

Comment: Is there any error in your whole code? The Binding files don't get generated when the build is unsuccessful. Go to Build tab strip above and Clean and Rebuild your project.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar this is the first what I did

Comment: @EduardUnruh Do you have an import statement like `import com.......ActivityMainBinding`? Probably Android studio didn't add it automatically

Comment: Yes it is there, the only problem is that all the views are unresolved reference, ActivityMainBinding is apparently initializing

Comment: Still your code should run.. Can you try `File` > `Invalidate caches and restart`

Comment: Probably last one in my bucket; add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in the module build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Bindings are generated based on the name of the XML layout file you've created for this activity.

I would suggest to double check if it exists & what it's called as your code indicates it should be called `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: Ofc it exists, everything broke after I removed kotlin-android-extensions and added buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}  just like in multiple tutorials. Before that everything worked. In case I didn't understand what you mean please explain it in more detail

Comment: Can you share the XML for `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: Please check the edit

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<layout>
```

at the most top place of your layout and

```
</layout>
```

at the most bottom place of your layout.

Comment: @Eduard Unruh  kindly try this