# how to add kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.* automatically to every new project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-android-extensions

Every time I start a new android app project I have to add

```
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

to the plugins block.

Is their a way to add them automatically to every new project?

Comment: I am pretty sure there'd be some setting for that, not sure right now. But just to add some info, kotlin synthetics are deprecated. Use view/data binding. But still you'd have to add the enable block to `build.gradle` yourself.

Comment: I'm still new and flowing tutorials and this is the way they do it
thank you so much for the info

Comment: isn't "kotlin-android-extensions" depreciated? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65179275/the-kotlin-android-extensions-gradle-plugin-is-deprecated)

Comment: it is but as I previously stated I'm following beginners tutorials and that's the way they do it
* thanks for commenting