# I can not use Kotlin functions in MainActivity.kt

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Am trying to use `repeat` function in the `MainActivity.kt` file but id doens seems working correctly here is the error that I have got:

[image]

**NB**: even `print` doesn't work

here is the suggested imports for `println`

[image]

I said maybe there are somthing missing in Kotin configuration so here is **my build.gradle (Module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication4"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    apply plugin : "kotlin-android"
    apply plugin : "kotlin-android-extensions"

}
```

**Build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.21"
    ext.supportLibVersion = "25.3.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Plugins is already installed:

[image]

Kotlin configuration in my project:

**Tools > Kotlin > Configure kotlin in Project**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(Opinion) Android studio is not really the best IDE to learn plain kotlin (and by plain I mean stuff not related to android)

(Answer)  In your case, if you want to print stuff (which will appear in the logcat btw) you would have to import the first thing, which is:
[image]

And you will have to (probably, not sure) do something similar for your `repeat`

Comment: Oh, also kotlin-android-extensions is deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65179275/the-kotlin-android-extensions-gradle-plugin-is-deprecated

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but am actually trying to make a mobile application using Kotlin, that is why I am using Andoird Studio. print was just an example to test if Kotlin packages can be imported correctly, but it seems like it does not.

For the repeat function  unfortunatelly there is not import suggestion, that is why I am wondering why I cannot Import that.

Same thing for the fuction Random for example, it gives me only the suggestions of Java packages and not Kotlin

Comment: Oh, sorry then, that's a bit interesting tho...

Comment: Could you make sure that your .kt files are associated with Kotlin? File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Types.

Comment: They are correcty associated (also, MainActivity.kt is the default file created by the IDE, so it has to be by default associated to Kotlin)

Comment: I would say Android Studio comes close to tying IntelliJ IDEA as being the best IDE for learning Kotlin. The only thing it lacks is a wizard for creating new projects that aren’t for Android.