# i applied plugin "kotlin-android-extension" on newly created project and project has simple UI and nothing did in the main activity

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

i apply the plugin "kotlin-android-extensions" it shows me that "the Kotlin android extension is no longer supported please use this migration guide I searched this error on Google and youtube but nothing helped me out to solve this problem please guide me  what should I do now to work further "

the project is newly creatd project i have just addess 4 buttons and 2 edit text nothing more

please help me solvingthis issue
As i am new to android studio please help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65179275/the-kotlin-android-extensions-gradle-plugin-is-deprecated)

Comment: And use databinding it is way faster solution for binding operations. kotlin-extensions uses findViewById at background and its an expensive operation.

Comment: @alpertign technically speaking viewbindings use findViewById as well. Its mostly a matter of scoping and caching that operation which was very unclear where, when or even if it happened in -extensions. They were somehow fine with flat activity layout but it got messy very fast when you started nesting containers.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Synthetics Plugin will be removed in Kotlin 1.8, which is expected to be released by the end of 2022. At that time, you won’t be able to update your project to newer Kotlin versions if it still depends on the Kotlin Android Extensions plugin. This means that now is the time to perform the necessary migrations in your projects.

Instead of synthetics, we recommend using [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), which generates type-safe binding classes from XML layout files. These bindings provide convenient access to view references and they work safely for layouts with multiple configurations. See the [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) for detailed instructions on how to adopt View Binding.