# Kotlin Textview id reference doesn't work with non-english characters

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

i'm create Textview with non-english id in my layout.xml then i want to use it in activity.kt

layout.xml,

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sonuç"
    .
    .
    ... />
```

activity.kt,

```
sonuç.text = "Hello World"
```

I'm getting an error, Unresolving reference:sonuç

What is the solution?

**Update!**

```
var sonuç : TextView = findViewById(R.id.sonuç)
sonuç.text = "Hello World"
```

This code worked fine in Kotlin. Why?

Comment: This may helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169562/unresolved-reference-kotlinx

Comment: The code worked fine because that's the proper way of accessing and manipulating visual elements in android. You have to find the view before you can modify its properties.

Comment: @Tharkius Except `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin allows you to access views via extension properties by using their ID as property name. So the real question is @HalilONCEN Did you `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` in your module build.gradle file? If you did and it still doesn't work, you should make a feature request here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissues%2Fkotlin

Comment: @EugenPechanec Didn't know about that, thanks for mentioning. That's a very neat plugin indeed :D

Comment: @EugenPechanec yes, this is in my build.gradle file `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

Comment: @HalilONCEN In that case it looks like the plugin does not support IDs with non-ASCII characters. I suggest you use only ASCII for now. In the meantime leave a bug report on YouTrack.

Comment: @EugenPechanec thanks. I'm reported. [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20299](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20299)

Comment: @HalilONCEN Awesome! You can post it as an answer (you can answer your own questions) and update it later when the feature is implemented.