# Unresolved Reference kotlinx

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am encountering with an error like

```
Unresolved reference: kotlinx
```

and the import statement is like

**kotlinx**.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

The bold code goes red and I am not able to use Kotlin Android extensions.This project was working fine for the past 2 days.

Seeing the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169562/unresolved-reference-kotlinx),I added

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
```

in the Project level build.gradle and

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

in module level but they also fail.

Android studio version : **3.0.1**

Kotlin version : **1.1.51**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You only need the Kotlin plugin in your project level `build.gradle` file, as it itself includes Kotlin Android Extensions. That would be the following: `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`. If this doesn't help, post both of your `build.gradle` files if possible.

Comment: It worked @zsmb13 . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need the Kotlin plugin in your project level build.gradle file, as it itself includes Kotlin Android Extensions - there's no need for another Gradle dependency. That would look something like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps something changed, or perhaps you just weren't using synthetics across multiple modules, but for synthetics to resolve one must include apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Answer (score 1):

> Unresolved reference: kotlin

The **`kotlin-gradle-plugin`** compiles **Kotlin** sources and modules.

The version of **Kotlin** to use is usually defined as the **`kotlin_version`** property:

```
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Your **`build.gradle`** ***(Project Level)*** will be

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: @DakshAgrawal  nope, You should call `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin`

Comment: I didn't mention it in the question but it was there

Comment: @DakshAgrawal no need `kotlin-android-extensions`

Comment: What do you mean "You should use `kotlin-gradle-plugin` instead of `kotlin-gradle-plugin`" - aren't those the same words?

Comment: Sorry, big mistake