# How to use Kotlinc coroutine in non android project?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to Kotlin and trying to learn asynchronous programming using coroutine. I am following Kotlin [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#coroutine-basics). But when I tried to compile my code, it showed me  error: "unresolved reference: kotlinx". So I just want to know, how can I use Coroutine in non android projects?

I am using Ubuntu terminal to compile the code.

Code Snippet

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*  
 fun main(args: Array<String>){     
     GlobalScope.launch{ 
       delay(1000L)
       println("World!")   
     }
     println("Hello,") 
     Thread.sleep(2000L)
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169562/unresolved-reference-kotlinx

Answer (score 3):

Download [kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.2.1.jar](https://bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx/kotlinx.coroutines/1.2.1#files/org%2Fjetbrains%2Fkotlinx%2Fkotlinx-coroutines-core%2F1.2.1), put it into the same folder where the source file (`Example.kt`) is, and compile it:

```
kotlinc Example.kt -cp kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.2.1.jar -include-runtime -d Example.jar
```

Run `Example.jar` using command

```
java -cp kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.2.1.jar:Example.jar ExampleKt
```

Comment: I'm too much of a newb at Kotlin and Java to figure out how to download from that page (`No direct downloads selected for this package.`). Much easier for me was [this one on mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.3.0)